# What does it mean when a file is owned by the user “system” and the group “system”? in android file system

Tags: linux, command, filesystems, android-source

I just trying to understand What does it mean when a file is owned by the user “system” and the group “system”? in the android file system.

In the android device file system

```
 root@xyz:/ # ls -l cache/
 drwxrwxr-x system   system            1969-12-31 17:00 SH_DIR
 drwx------ system   system            2021-06-02 23:26 backup
 drwxrwx--- root     root              2021-06-02 23:17 lost+found
 drwxrwxrwx root     root              2021-06-08 02:12 test
 drwxrwx--- system   cache             2021-06-07 05:40 recovery
```

For SH_DIR and backup have owned by the user “system” and the group “system”.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [android.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will post as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX based operating systems, if you create a file it gets your user as owner and your user's primary group as it's group. It doesn't necessarily mean anything else here. If you create a user and not explicitly assign any group to them they will get a group created with the same name and assigned as a primary group.

Comment: If change the ower name from "system" to "root" for SH_DIR directory, We will get any security issues in the feature.  I am trying to understand more about "system"